# Create public view of Node.js logs on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a Node.js app I built and deployed to Heroku that I use internally on my team to perform automated tasks against a 3rd party tool's API. I don't mind that I have to keep a terminal window open to keep an eye on the logs, but what would be really sweet is to put up a real-time view (heroku logs --tail) that anyone on my team could go look at to see the apps status, etc.

I've looked around and haven't found anyone else doing it.

Answer (score 1):

heroku has an addon for logentries that is pretty sweet. it will give you parseable, searchable logs including live streaming them.

logentries:
https://logentries.com/

logentries add on:
https://elements.heroku.com/addons/logentries

other logging addons:
https://elements.heroku.com/addons#logging

you can always implement your own solution using herokus logplex system, which has an api:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logplex

or you can go deeper and implement something like the elk stack or any other similar technology:
https://www.elastic.co/webinars/introduction-elk-stack

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!